# i can't read file in C

Tags: c, readfile

I am a student and now I develop model of small processor in C language. Program, which processor must do is in file. Now I try to write a program, which will be read something from file. It does not work! I work in Ubuntu 10.04 and write code in GVIM. There is a archieve of my program : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48293648/testfolder.tar.bz2 
Errors: in console I see only "1" symbols, not "hello world"
Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEBUG 0

void main(void)
{
FILE *f;
int c;
f = fopen("text.txt", "r");
if(f == NULL)
    printf("ERROR opening file");
while( (c=getc(f) != EOF))
    {
        printf("%6x\n",c);
    };
fclose(f);
#if DEBUG
printf("DEBUG\n");
#endif
printf("ololo\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`while( (c=getc(f) != EOF))` has a parenthesis in the wrong place; you are assigning to `c` the result of `getc(f) != EOF`.

(Also, why do you have the program simply continue with an invalid `(FILE *)` if the `fopen()` fails?  The most likely result is a core dump.)

Answer (score 0):

while( (c=getc(f)) != EOF)
Will be work well, FYI